# How to handle navigationController on other class

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

i have class like this

DrillDownAppAppDelegate.h
PictureCell.h
RootViewController.h
SlideShowViewController.h

DrillDownAppAppDelegate.m
PictureCell.m
RootViewController.m
SlideShowViewController.m

i want to hide my navigation bar,in class SlideShowViewController when i tap on the screen 
but it doesn't work
my code is

[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming RootViewController is the visible view controller on the UINavigationController stack, simply push SlideShowViewController as normal, however in SlideShowViewController, include this code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
}
```